# Stumped Android Notification not Unique

Tags: android, android-intent, handler, android-notifications

So I've tried everything I know how to make a unique notification in Android and I have this working in another app but not in a Handler. I basically have this:

```
NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification n = new Notification();

// Create the notification
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "No GPS!", System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
intent.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), msg.arg1, intent,0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),
Integer.toString(msg.arg1), mString, pendingIntent);

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(0, notification);

// Give it an ID
nManager.notify(msg.arg1, n);
```

But it is not generating unique notifications, they keep being overridden. I tried to use msg.arg1 to control the uniqueness, but this doesn't seem to be working any ideas?

Comment: have u checked whether the msg.arg1 is unique for every notification....try giving timestamp for instance....

Comment: It is unique but I replaced all the arg1's never the less with timestamp and it is still showing up both updates in the same notification bar.